# Injecting git branches info into swagger ui info

Tags: git, swagger, swagger-ui

with the microservice architecture, for example of 9 web services.

I must deploy two web services (ws1, ws3) in order to test my modifications, so in the best cases I deploy only ws1 and ws3, and I test, on the other hand I do not know which branches were deployed on the web services ws2, ws4, ws5, ws6, ws7, ws8, ws9, by the other developers, and if it turns out that they have deployed another branch (for example branch notWhatIWant su ws6), I must also deployed this ws6!

Ask the developer sometimes is useless, because they answer with I do not remember.
So currently I deploy the 9 web services each time to have the git branches I want !!
which is very long with 9 web service!

is it possible to inject git branch information into swagger ?
when i go to /info, i want to find the deployed git branche,

Comment: I would use something like [GitVersion](gitversion.net) to get a semantial version based on a git tag and the current branch at build time. Exactly how would of course depend on which language you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your CI build you can read the branch name from `.git/HEAD` with a shell script and `sed` the value into some properties file. Then read the file and expose its content in some kind of `/version` endpoint.

But strategically - this isn't how web services should be developed. WS1 shouldn't care about which branch WS2 is using. Ideally when WS1 starts to use WS2 API - that API is already in master.

And in general the fewer branches you have and shorter their life - the easier it is to keep you head straight. Read on tunk-based development, Branching by Abstraction, Feature Toggles.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But knowing which branch was deployed on ws7 or ws8 is important in my case, because I want to know which branch was deployed and with which last commit,

Comment: I understand that it's important to you, I'm just saying that it means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the git information are out of the box available in a project. You need to implement here a logic to fetch those information and add it to your project. If you have this information you can add an controller that will show this information.

Here is a Spring example on how to fetch those information: [Baeldung Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-git-information)

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'll test it